# How to block NVDA screen reader read entire page?

Tags: birt, screen-readers

I have designed a BIRT / Magellan report, which has to be ADA compliance (Americans with Disabilities Act of 1990). We are using NVDA screen reader to read out the web output of the report. Now NVDA is reading entire report table - "One table with 2 rows 3 columns ...". I want NVDA to read specific areas or specific text from my report, not each and every component.

I have tried display:none or speak:none. It's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a tutorial on how to use a screen reader.  By default, NVDA has "read all" turned on, which you can turn off in settings. There are lots of ways to navigate through a webpage - sequentially using the down arrow key, by DOM element such as 'B' for buttons, 'T' for tables, 'H' for headings, tabbing through the page, etc.

You should be mainly concerned that your webpage is structured properly using native HTML elements as much as possible (<table>, <ul>, <h1>, etc). If your page is coded properly, then it will be easy for a screen reader user to navigate using the various ways mentioned above.

You didn't post any code so I can't make any recommendations on whether you need to change anything.

Here's a recording from an accessibility meetup on some basic NVDA settings - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytx22kHA6TE&t=852s

Here's another meetup recording on basic accessibility testing, which includes showing how to navigate using NVDA - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9TkuDygsezg&t=500s

And here is the [complete NVDA User Guide](https://www.nvaccess.org/files/nvda/documentation/userGuide.html).  In particular, see the "[6.1. Single Letter Navigation](https://www.nvaccess.org/files/nvda/documentation/userGuide.html#SingleLetterNavigation)" section which has information on how to navigate as I mentioned above.